# Hibernate - strategy="increment" in table ,Multiple tomcat gives duplicate primary key

Tags: java, hibernate

- Single Database MySql
- Multiple Tomcat on different location which shared same code
- Hibernate 5.2.2
- On Table level
- @GenericGenerator(name="employee" , strategy="increment")
- @GeneratedValue(generator="employee")

When another server enters value gives duplicate primary key error

In future we are also supporting Sql Server, Oracle, HSQL

Comment: will @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

> **Increment** 
>   generates identifiers of type long, short or int that are
>   unique only when no other process is inserting data into the same
>   table. Do not use in a cluster.
>
> **Identity** 
>   supports identity columns in DB2, MySQL, MS SQL Server,
>   Sybase and HypersonicSQL. The returned identifier is of type long,
>   short or int.
>
> **Sequence** uses a sequence in DB2, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SAP DB, McKoi or
>   a generator in Interbase. The returned identifier is of type long,
>   short or int

Ref : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id

Comment: will identity work with Oracle? I forgot to mention in question, edited with data.

Comment: No, for Oracle I recommend sequence

Comment: If you want to make the code generic so that it runs fine in both oracle and MySQL the use sequence. It's future proof.